# Turn an HTML/CSS element into a re-usable AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an existing HTML based web UI for an administration panel.

I am trying to take all of the HTML components, and turn them into re-usable AngularJS directives so I can embed them in a page with minimal effort.

Here is one I'm stuck on:

```
<section class="dash-tile">
    <div class="tile-title" ng-controller="testCtrl">{{test}}</div>
    <div class="tile-stats"><b>8068</b>
    </div>
    <div class="progress progress-xs mt5 mb10">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile-footer">
        Based on new sales
    </div>
</section>
```

This snippet, used inside of my .html GUI will create a small box shaped title with some data inside.

Could someone give me an example of how to turn this into a reusable component?

So far I'm here:

```
admin.directive('whiteBox', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA', //restrict the directive to ONLY an attribute or element
        replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<section class="dash-tile">' +
                                    '<div class="tile-title" ng-controller="testCtrl">' + '{{test}}' + '</div>'
                                    + '<div class="tile-stats">' + '<b>' + '8068' + '</b>'
                                    + '</div>'
                                    + '<div class="progress progress-xs mt5 mb10">'
                                        + '<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">'
                                    + '</div>'
                                    + '</div>'
                                    + '<div class="tile-footer">'
                                    +   'Based on new sales'
                                    + '</div>'
                                + '</section> ',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // add events
        }
    };
```

But this breaks the application for some reason.

Comment: Define "breaks the application for some reason".

Comment: No console errors, everything is fine in the console. But the directive does not load on screen.

Comment: Well, if that's your full directive, you're missing a closing curly brace, parenthesis, and semicolon.  It seems to work fine other than that [see jsBin](http://jsbin.com/nazepobito/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I don't see you using the directive in html ...

Comment: It is embedded using <div whiteBox></div> in the html

Comment: As per your last comment, you would need to do `white-box`, not `whiteBox`

Comment: Bingo, I was not aware of this convention. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*AngularJS* uses the following **convention**

If you name your directive `whiteBox`, in HTML you use it `white-box`.

AngularJS declaration

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
```

HTML usage

```
<div my-directive></div>
```